# seabornで（エラーバー付きの）棒グラフを描くには

Tags: python, python3, pandas, seaborn

seabornにて、（エラーバー付きの）棒グラフを描きたいと思っています。

目標は、以下のdf.plot.bar()のように、「体育会出身」「その他」ふたつの項目を棒グラフとして表示させることです。

ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
a=[[63,237,300],[37,163,200],[100,400,500]]

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(a,index=['体育会出身','その他','合計'],columns=['主任以上','役職なし','合計'])
df
```

[image: 元のDataFrame]

```
# 必要な行、列を抽出
df=df.loc[['体育会出身','その他'],['主任以上','合計']]
df
```

[image: 必要な項目を抽出してDataFrameを再構築した]

```
# 比率にする
df=df.div(df['合計'],axis=0)
df
```

[image: 比率にする]

```
# 必要な列のみ抽出する
df=df['主任以上']
df
```

[image: 必要な列のみ抽出]

```
#dataframe.plot.bar()にて描写する
df.plot.bar()
df
```

[image: df.plot.bar()にて描写]

```
#seaborn.barplot(df)にて描写
#「体育会出身」「その他」の２つの項目とならず、１つになってしまう。
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(df)
```

[image: sns.barplotにて評者]

Comment: `df` が `pandas.Series` 型なので `sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df)` など。

Comment: sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df)にて、グラフがうまく描写できました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

データを作成する`df=df['主任以上']`でpandasのDataFrameではなくSeriesが出来ているからでしょう。

`df=pd.DataFrame(df['主任以上'])`とするか、最初から以下のようにその形でDataFrameを作成すれば良いと思われます。

```
a=[[0.21],[0.185]]
df=pd.DataFrame(a,index=['体育会出身','その他'],columns=['主任以上'])
```

グラフの作成はこちらのように`x`,`y`,`data`を指定すれば良いでしょう。
`color`は指定しないとそれぞれの棒が別の色になります。

```
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y="主任以上", data=df, color='steelblue')
```

---

その上で、棒に付いたヒゲのような部分も表示したいならば、そのためのデータを用意する必要があるでしょう。
seabornではなくmatplotlibですが、これらの記事とかでその部分の話題を扱っているので、参考にしてみてください。
[Pandas.DataFrame.plotとmatplotlib.plot,エラーバー(yerr)表示を微調整したいのだが・・・。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/49348/26370)
[pythonによるエラーバーの作図方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75767/26370)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。おかげさまで、思い通りできましたー
以下の点、ひとつひとつ確認しています。

１）sns.barplot()には、Seriesは不可である。
２）なので、df=df['主任以上']　#Seriesを、df=pd.DataFrame(df['主任以上']) #DataFrameとする（元のクロス図から行・列を抽出せず、最初から当該クロス図を作成した方がスマート）
３）sns.barplot()には、x、ｙの引数を入れ以下のようにする。
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y="主任以上", data=df, color='steelblue')

「ヒゲ」（エラーバー）については、貼っていただいたURLを参考に、今後、勉強してまいります。

Comment: いえ、@metropolis さんがコメントされたように、おそらくpandas.Seriesのままでもパラメータの指定方法を工夫すれば出来るでしょう。検索して見つかる例にpandas.DataFrameを使った例が目立ったのでそれを応用したものです。